# SQL server Chinese, French, Arabic Language

Tags: sql-server

I would like to save in SQL server Database, in a same field, different languages (Chinese, Japanese, French, And Arabic characters). Is it possible and how can I do?
I worked with the collation of the tables but I cannot save Arabic characters if I choose a Chinese collation (Chinese_Simplified_Pinyin_100_BIN). Is there a best collation?

Comment: Use `NVARCHAR`, See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer, but I have the following problem.

when I execute the query

Update Address set Street2 = 'أهلاً و سهلاً' where DBId = 1 and Id = 2

and after select the field I see ????? ? ?????.

but not in Chinese or Japanese or French.

I dont't understand.

billy21

Comment: You need to provide more details in the actual question. Where are you getting "???" is it in SSMS? is it in your app front end? Please update your question and post additional details. I suggest you take the time read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask